# Create multi accounts for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I am trying to create a user database with defined ID numbers.
However the wordpress database encrypted password, which I cant insert the users into database,

There are two approach I am thinking but I cannot finish it

- generate password before insert into wp_user table.
    -- however I had no idea on how to generate
- find some plugin that do for me.
    -- no idea which one fit from plugin pools

The two question I would wanna ask
how wordpress password work?
any plugin for multi user inserting?

Answer (score 1):

you can either use the [PHP md5()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) in your PHP file to encrypt the password or [MySQL MD5()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) in your query.

If you are working within the Wordpress environment, you can use [wp_insert_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) to create your users using a selected ID.

Comment: Thanks, so how if I wanna add multiple user at the same time? Not other method than Looping the data ?

Comment: `wp_insert_user()` takes only one user at a time. You might try a big MySQL insert if you want, but I don't know any side effects that can occur.